# Formulários bloqueados para edição

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Boa tarde !
Amigos, criei layout para inserir materiais no estoque, sendo um item por linha. Caso a pessoa queira adicionais mais itens, clica no botão e uma nova div é inserida no HTMl. Segue código HTML:

```
          <div class="col-12 d-flex" id="info-produto">
            <div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
              <label for="produto">Produto*</label>
              <input type="text" id="produto" class="form-control is valid" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
              <label for="unidade-medida">Unidade de medida*</label>
              <select id="unidade-medida" class="form-control">
                <option value="unidade">Unidade</option>
                <option value="caixa">Caixa</option>
                <option value="metro">Metro</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 mt-3">
              <label for="quantidade">QTD*</label>
              <input type="number" id="quantidade" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
              <label for="quantidade-por-unidade">QTD/UND*</label>
              <input type="number" id="quantidade-por-unidade" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 mt-3">
              <fieldset disabled="disabled">
                <label for="total">Total</label>
                <input type="number" id="total" class="form-control">
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
              <label for="valor">Valor</label>
              <input type="text" id="valor" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-3 ml-3" id="adicionar-outro-produto">Adicionar mais itens</button>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Segue código JS:

```
var botao = document.querySelector('#adicionar-outro-produto')
botao.addEventListener("click",function(){

  var divproduto = document.createElement('div')
  var produto = document.createElement('input:text')
  produto.classList.add("form-control")
  divproduto.appendChild(produto)
  divproduto.classList.add('col-md-4')


  var divunidade = document.createElement('div')
  var unidade = document.createElement('select')
  var opcaoum = document.createElement('option')
  opcaoum.textContent="Unidade"
  var opcaodois = document.createElement('option')
  opcaodois.textContent="Caixa"
  var opcaotres = document.createElement('option')
  opcaotres.textContent="Metro"
  unidade.appendChild(opcaoum)
  unidade.appendChild(opcaodois)
  unidade.appendChild(opcaotres)
  unidade.classList.add("form-control")
  divunidade.classList.add('col-md-2')
  divunidade.appendChild(unidade)

  var divquantidade = document.createElement('div')
  var quantidade = document.createElement('input:number')
  quantidade.classList.add("form-control")
  divquantidade.classList.add('col-md-1')
  divquantidade.appendChild(quantidade)

  var divqtdunidade = document.createElement('div')
  var qtdunidade = document.createElement('input:number')
  qtdunidade.classList.add("form-control")
  divqtdunidade.classList.add('col-md-2')
  divqtdunidade.appendChild(qtdunidade)

  var divtotal = document.createElement('div')
  var fild = document.createElement('fieldset')
  var total = document.createElement('input:number')
  total.classList.add("form-control")
  fild.appendChild(total)
  divtotal.classList.add('col-md-1')
  divtotal.appendChild(fild)

  var divvalor= document.createElement('div')
  var valor = document.createElement('input:text')
  divvalor.appendChild(valor)
  valor.classList.add('form-control')
  divvalor.classList.add('col-md-2')

  var infoprodutos = document.createElement('div')
  infoprodutos.appendChild(divproduto)
  infoprodutos.appendChild(divunidade)
  infoprodutos.appendChild(divquantidade)
  infoprodutos.appendChild(divqtdunidade)
  infoprodutos.appendChild(divtotal)
  infoprodutos.appendChild(divvalor)

  infoprodutos.classList.add('d-flex')
  infoprodutos.classList.add('col-md-12')
  infoprodutos.classList.add('mt-3')

  var adesao = document.querySelector('#pai')
  adesao.appendChild(infoprodutos)

})
```

Porém os novos formulários inseridos não são editáveis. O que fazer ?

Comment: leia os dados da linha e mostre em campos editáveis, numa linha ou num popup, ai pode editar e atualizar

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o problema esta nas linha com *createElement*, não é possível declarar o elemento definindo a propriedade de tipo como esta esta sendo feito *input:number*. Para fazer isso crie o elemento apenas com *input*, e após isso atribua o tipo de campo desejado.

```
var quantidade = document.createElement('input');
quantidade.type = "number";
```

ou

```
var quantidade = document.createElement('input');
quantidade.setAttribute("type", "number");
```

veja

> var elemento = document.createElement(nomeDaTag);
>
> nomeDaTag é uma string que especifica o tipo do elemento a ser criado. O nodeName do elemento criado é inicializado com o valor da nomeDaTag. Não use nomes qualificados (como "html:a") com este método.

Para mais detalhes
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement